# why the treatment-dummy coefficient in a DID reg is different from that of a reg for the pre-treatment period?

Tags: difference-in-difference

The value of the "ever_treated" coefficient obtained with this DID regression is .0397682:

```
keep if (first_treated==3 | first_treated==0) & (period==2 | period==3)

gen after=0
replace after=1 if period==3
reg vote_share ever_treated##after

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    14,710
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 14706)     =   1784.25
       Model |  42.0192229         3  14.0064076   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  115.442224    14,706  .007850008   R-squared       =    0.2669
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2667
       Total |  157.461447    14,709  .010705109   Root MSE        =     .0886

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        vote_share | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    1.ever_treated |   .0397682   .0104217     3.82   0.000     .0193403    .0601961
           1.after |   .1057864   .0014683    72.05   0.000     .1029083    .1086645
                   |
ever_treated#after |
              1 1  |   .0390382   .0147385     2.65   0.008     .0101488    .0679275
                   |
             _cons |   .1798707   .0010383   173.24   0.000     .1778356    .1819058
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the value of the "ever_treated" coefficient obtained with this regression is again .0397682

```
keep if (first_treated==3 | first_treated==0) & (period==2)
reg vote_share ever_treated

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     7,355
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 7353)      =     31.67
       Model |  .114304309         1  .114304309   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   26.540137     7,353   .00360943   R-squared       =    0.0043
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0042
       Total |  26.6544413     7,354  .003624482   Root MSE        =    .06008

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  vote_share | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ever_treated |   .0397682   .0070668     5.63   0.000     .0259152    .0536212
       _cons |   .1798707    .000704   255.49   0.000     .1784906    .1812508
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far so good.

The problem arises when I add covariates.

With the DID regression I have -.0194929:

```
keep if (first_treated==3 | first_treated==0) & (period==2 | period==3)
gen after=0
replace after=1 if period==3

reg vote_share ever_treated##after tasso_attivita_annoElez tasso_occup_annoElez tasso_disoccup_annoElez popComune_annoElez popSLL_20a39tot
> piccoli AD pop_laureataSLL, cluster(idcomune)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     14,704
                                                F(10, 7351)       =    2262.04
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.6042
                                                Root MSE          =     .06512

                                      (Std. err. adjusted for 7,352 clusters in idcomune)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        |               Robust
             vote_share | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         1.ever_treated |  -.0194929   .0061519    -3.17   0.002    -.0315523   -.0074335
                1.after |   .1278977   .0009282   137.78   0.000      .126078    .1297173
                        |
     ever_treated#after |
                   1 1  |   .0254109   .0075165     3.38   0.001     .0106764    .0401454
                        |
tasso_attivita_annoElez |   .1010534   .0024746    40.84   0.000     .0962026    .1059043
   tasso_occup_annoElez |  -.1165163   .0027608   -42.20   0.000    -.1219283   -.1111042
tasso_disoccup_annoElez |  -.0465009   .0013333   -34.88   0.000    -.0491145   -.0438873
     popComune_annoElez |   7.16e-08   5.67e-08     1.26   0.206    -3.94e-08    1.83e-07
 popSLL_20a39totpiccoli |   .5358987   .0848864     6.31   0.000      .369497    .7023004
                     AD |   .0992816   .0734041     1.35   0.176    -.0446115    .2431748
        pop_laureataSLL |   .3712255   .0252147    14.72   0.000     .3217974    .4206537
                  _cons |   .6185984   .0499784    12.38   0.000     .5206263    .7165705
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And with the other regression I have .0051015:

```
keep if (first_treated==3 | first_treated==0) & (period==2)
reg vote_share ever_treated tasso_attivita_annoElez tasso_occup_annoElez tasso_disoccup_annoElez popComune_annoElez popSLL_20a39totpiccoli
>  AD pop_laureataSLL, cluster(idcomune)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =      7,352
                                                F(8, 7351)        =     295.00
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.2538
                                                Root MSE          =     .05203

                                      (Std. err. adjusted for 7,352 clusters in idcomune)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        |               Robust
             vote_share | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           ever_treated |   .0051015   .0057456     0.89   0.375    -.0061615    .0163644
tasso_attivita_annoElez |   .0681392   .0025118    27.13   0.000     .0632153    .0730631
   tasso_occup_annoElez |  -.0774181   .0028267   -27.39   0.000    -.0829592    -.071877
tasso_disoccup_annoElez |  -.0306189   .0013168   -23.25   0.000    -.0332003   -.0280375
     popComune_annoElez |   7.57e-08   5.62e-08     1.35   0.178    -3.45e-08    1.86e-07
 popSLL_20a39totpiccoli |  -.3757719   .0810383    -4.64   0.000    -.5346303   -.2169135
                     AD |   -.339289   .0704147    -4.82   0.000     -.477322    -.201256
        pop_laureataSLL |   .3240333   .0250621    12.93   0.000     .2749043    .3731623
                  _cons |   .7365195   .0485051    15.18   0.000     .6414356    .8316034
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since the "ever_treated" coefficient in the DID regression represents the intercept of the treated group, shouldn't it always be equal to that obtained with the linear regression ran for just the pre-treatment period, as it happens in the no-covariates case?

Edit: some of the covariates are time-varying, some are not.

Thank you.